# How to get permalink of custom post type that filter by category in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type like 'articles' and use built-in categories like 'rock, pop, jazz, etc' to categorised this articles. I have a permalink for 'articles' archive also have permalink to and category archive page like jazz archive page.

But also I want to permalink to articles that filter by specified categories. my archive page also handle this conditions but I can't get permalink for this page!

When I type this address to browser 'index.php?post-type=articles&category-name=jazz' this url redirect to /category/jazz/?post-type=articles but I want this is apear in this format /articles/category/jazz

Comment: You probably have to use the [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) class. There should be lots of tutorials on the web. I'd love to give a go at your case but can't right now

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you first need to register your category with the custom post type and then you can assign categories and have the desired result. Use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type();` in order to assign category taxonomy to your custom post type. You can get an example here :  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type

Comment: My Category is built-in wordpress category and in Post Type Registration I assign this type to posy type, In admin panel I see category box, My problem only in url!